# Apply effect on an unselected tab anchor

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a way to apply a jQuery UI effect, such as the `pulsate` effect (as described [here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)) on an unselected tab of a tab strip, leaving that tab unselected?

What I'm trying to obtain is to tell the user to pay attention on a *tab X* while he's working on a *tab Y*, because some action caused the *tab X* to reload its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customized [tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) widget with the notification behavior built into it:

```
$.widget( "app.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {

    // Applies the "ui-state-highlight" class
    // to the given tab index.
    notify: function( index ) {
        if ( this.active.index() === index ) {
            return;    
        }
        this.tabs.eq( index )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    },

    // Removes the "ui-state-highlight" class
    // from the given tab index.
    unnotify: function( index ) {
        this.tabs.eq( index )
            .removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );    
    },

    // Make sure active tabs don't have the
    // "ui-state-highlight" class applied.
    _toggle: function( e, ui ) {
        this._super( e, ui );
        this.unnotify( ui.newTab.index() );
    }

});

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs()
        .tabs( "notify", 1 );
});
```

You're basically just adding two new methods to the widget - `notify()` and `unnotify()`. The `_toggle()` method we've overridden here just makes sure that when we navigate to the tab that's been notified, we *turn off* the notification by calling `unnotify()`.

This code is just adding the `ui-state-highlight` class as the notification mechanism, but that can easily be replaced with something else, like an effect. Here's the original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/e4cpv/).